# Nitric acid decomposition

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have a problem with the decomposition reaction of Nitric acid($\ce{HNO3}$) by light.
My problem: is that reaction is a redox reaction?
If it is please tell me the oxidation and reduction (balanced) reactions seperately.

Comment: Why do you think it's photochemical? Nitric acid is sold in clear colorless bottles.

Comment: @Zhe no, nitric acid is subjected to decomposition due to light. See my answer below.

Comment: Interesting. Never seen the brown bottle before... Thanks! @NilayGhosh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, nitric acid is a strong oxidizing agent which get reduce to nitrogen oxides on reacting with metals which act as reducing agent thus forming a redox reaction. But in this case, only nitric acid is involved which get reduced to nitrogen oxides on reaction with air/light. So, this may be called oxidation reaction where nitric acid gets oxidized. From wikipedia article of [nitric acid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_acid):

> **Nitric acid is subject to thermal or light decomposition and for this reason it was often stored in brown glass bottles:**
>
> $$\ce{ 4 HN^{V}O3 → 2 H2O + 4 N^{IV}O2 + O2}$$
>
> This reaction may give rise to some non-negligible variations in the
>   vapor pressure above the liquid because the nitrogen oxides produced
>   dissolve partly or completely in the acid.
>
> The nitrogen dioxide ($\ce{NO2}$) remains dissolved in the nitric acid
>   coloring it yellow or even red at higher temperatures. While the pure
>   acid tends to give off white fumes when exposed to air, acid with
>   dissolved nitrogen dioxide gives off reddish-brown vapors, leading to
>   the common name "red fuming acid" or "fuming nitric acid" – the most
>   concentrated form of nitric acid at Standard Temperature and
>   Pressure (STP). Nitrogen oxides ($\ce{NO_x}$) are soluble in nitric
>   acid.

There are some old papers([here](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j150530a004) and [here](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/1912/CT/ct9120100131)) which discuss the mechanism of nitric acid decomposition. Give a quick read on the papers and you will understand the mechanism of the reaction.